# Determine function argument starting adresses

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a "c" program, which gives following arguments for external x86 function:

```
extern "C" int fun(unsigned char *par1, unsigned char *par2, unsigned int par3);
```

The length of par1 is defined.

How to determine addresses in which the arguments starts?

I know that par1 starts at  `[ebp+8]` and e.g. par2 starts at `[ebp+16]`

I don't know how to determine where par3 starts?

Comment: Is this 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9pvqgw

Comment: it is 32-bit for now

Comment: From what I remember about x86, not x86-64, the args are passed on the stack in reverse order. Relative to the stack frame, it should be at the base of the frame?

Comment: As from I tested I should be adding (with one argument)

Comment: Sorry, I'm doing `push ebp`
 `mov ebp, esp` before

Comment: the n-arg have address `(void**)_AddressOfReturnAddress() + n` where n = 1,2,3.. of course in case `__stdcall` or `__cdecl`. but not `__fastcall`

Comment: Par2 is at ebp+12 and par3 is at ebp+16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The caller pushes the arguments in reverse order, according to the x86 ABI, then calls `fun`. The `call` instruction pushes `eip` onto the stack before jumping to `fun`. Then, you set up your stack frame, making `ebp` the top of the stack, so arg1 must be 8 bytes up from the stack frame:

```
      higher mem
+----------+---------+
| arg 3    | 4 bytes | push arg 3
+----------+---------+           (ebp + 16)
| arg 2    | 4 bytes | push arg 2
+----------+---------+           (ebp + 12)
| arg 1    | 4 bytes | push arg 1
+----------+---------+           (ebp + 8)
| ret addr | 4 bytes | call fun
+----------+---------+           (ebp + 4)
| old ebp  | 4 bytes | push ebp; mov ebp, esp
+----------+---------+ <-------- (ebp + 0) STACK FRAME START
       lower mem
```

Comment: function can at all not use *ebp* frame

Comment: You omitted the saved ebp from the stack diagram. It is on the stack below the ret addr. But arg1 is at ebp+8 — you got that part right. Saved ebp is at ebp+0 and ret addr is at ebp+4. In my experience, stack diagrams show the address of each item on the stack *below* the item, instead of above it.

Comment: @RbMm, while it is not necessary to use ebp for the stack frame, the question does say that it is used, so I’m not sure why you would question it.